# Using ".jar" file imported to JSF 2.2 Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I'm new to JSF and I've been looking into some tutorials and posts(It's hard to find good/new material) but I still don't get how to import a ".jar" file to my JSF 2.2 project.

I have this ".jar" file that uses some ".so"(shared objects) files. So I copied and pasted them inside the WEB-INF/lib folder(as some tutorials suggested). Then I right clicked my project and Choosed: Properties> Java Build Path> Add External Jars and pointed to the ".jar" I mentioned above.

After that I created my Bean and my view as described:

Bean:

```
package somepackage;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import uk.ac.ox.cs.fdr.*; // This is the jar file I want to use

@ManagedBean
public class SomeBean {

  private String text = "";

  public String getText(){
      return(text);
  }

  public void setText(String ntext){
      this.text = ntext;
  }

  public void foo(){
      String aux = "";

      try {
            Session session = new Session(); //this class is defined inside the .jar file
            session.loadFile("intro.csp");
            //
            for (Assertion assertion : session.assertions()) {
                assertion.execute(null);//Assertion is also a class from this jar
                aux.concat(assertion.toString()+" "+
                    (assertion.passed() ? "Passed" : "Failed")); // here I concatenate the string to my auxiliary string
            }
        }
        catch (InputFileError error) {
            setText(error.toString());
        }
        catch (FileLoadError error) {
            setText(error.toString());
        }
        this.setText(aux);
        fdr.libraryExit();
  }
```

}

And my view:

```
<h:form>
   <textarea>#{someBean.text}</textarea>
   <h:commandButton value="Press Me" action="#{someBean.foo}"/>
</h:form>
```

When I run my server (I'm using Tomcat 8 with ecplise), everything starts normally (I get 2 warnings, but I saw in other posts that I could ignore then) they are:

```
Classpath entry /home/rrs/workspace/myProjct/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/fdr.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.      myProjct        P/myProjct  Classpath Dependency Validator Message
```

and

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Method must have signature "String method(), String method()...
```

So I go to http://localhost:8080/myProjct/index.jsf and try to use my button (the idea is that when I press It, foo() function will be called and the textarea will display some text). But It looks like that from the "try{}" to the "fdr.libraryExit" the code isn't executed (the console doesn't display any error, but the textarea is not updated). I have no idea why this is happening.

PS: I pasted the "intro.csp" inside the project (right clicked the project and choose paste).

Comment: Undo everything you did in *Build Path*. Just dropping JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` was been sufficient.

Comment: Hey, BalusC, I did what you mentioned, I actually works fine, but I discovered that my program is not work because It can't find the file "intro.csp" on the line "session.loadFile("intro.csp")"; Is there a special place where I should put it? I copied and pasted It indside the project directly, also tryied pasting It inside the WEB-INF/lib, but everytime I get:
<unknown location>: Could not open the file 'intro.csp'

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the deployment assembly part. You need to check the Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly to place the jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your server.

Comment: Hey, Fernando, how do I do this deployment assembly part?

Comment: Hi Rafael, You have to do the following  1.- Right Click in your project. -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly  2.- Add your Web-inf/lib folder to source column and you have to put it to WEB-INF/lib/ deploy path column.

Build & Restart the server

Comment: I think this link might help you [deployment assembly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/jboss-eclipse/eclipse-web-lib-configuration)

Comment: Hi fernando, The part to add to the source column I did It, but I'm not getting the part to add to the deployment. if I click this column and try to add the WEB-INF/lib It says that this folder already exists

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't see the link you posted, I will read It now.